# react-native-permissions: If RESULTS.DENIED, is there a way to tell if user manually denied?

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, permission-denied, react-native-permissions

I'm looking at the following Android Flow for [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions). `RESULTS.DENIED` can be returned either in the scenario `Is the permission already granted` -> `NO` or `Is the permission still requestable` -> `YES`. In other words, it will return `RESULTS.DENIED` both when the app first calls `check()` *and* when the user clicks `deny`.

Is there any way to distinguish between these two scenarios?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When permission is DENIED, it continues to be requestable then the app can ask permission again with a popup permission modal.

In the worst-case scenario, when the user checks NO NOT ASK AGAIN, the permission is BLOCKED and not requestable anymore. If that happens, the app can ask a user to grant permission manually from app settings.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I'm wondering though is if there's a way to distinguish between the two scenarios I mentioned ^^.